# What's the difference "Ich käme" and "Ich würde kommen"?

Tags: subjunctive, conjugation

I'm told they are the same. Are they?
In Germany, is one form more preferred in spoken/written German? I'm asking specifically about Germany, not other German speaking populations.

As a German student, if they are the same, does that mean I can skip learning the Subjunctive II form of verbs altogether, and just use "würde" + infinitive instead??

Comment: Please don't use "Subjunctive" for the German Konjunktiv. That's not the same thing.

Comment: @tofro please stop spreading misinformation. It is both common and appropriate to use the term *subjunctive* here. See for instance https://www.dartmouth.edu/~deutsch/Grammatik/Subjunctive/KonjunktivII.html. (Both terms are Latin anyway.)

Comment: @DavidVogt Well, the simplest "not-the-same-thing" argument is that you can use one in reported speech and cannot do that in the other language. Another one is usage for orders and requests, where they are also not the same thing.

Comment: What's the same thing as what? *Subjunctive* is an English term, but not a term specific to a mood or form of the English language. For instance, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood talks about lots of languages. As I said, many German grammars written in English use the term.

Comment: @DavidVogt Which doesn't make it *exactly right*. Yes, English subjunctive and German Konjunktiv are very similar. Agree. They're still not the same. It's like the claim that tigers and lions would be the same to Africans and Asians, because that's somehow something they tend to know.

Comment: It's not about one thing being the same thing as another. *Subjunctive* is a term used in English when talking about German. See Bruce Duncan, Wikipedia, Hammer's German grammar, Curme's German grammar ... So you have no basis for claiming that using the term is wrong.

Comment: @DavidVogt: each language has its own grammatics and it is a good idea to use the correct grammatical terms for each. German has no "subjunctive" like English has no "Konjunktiv", Einglish has no "Akkusativobjekt" and no "Dativobjekt" whereas German has no "direct" or "indirect" objects - and so on, and so on. "Oh, Paul!" is not an "English Vocativ" and "mit dem Hammer" is not a "German Instrumentalis".

Comment: People use language to talk about language. When speaking English, one uses the term *subjunctive* for moods and forms of lots of different languages, among them the English and German subjunctive, respectively. If this seems strange to you then the reason quite frankly is that you haven't read enough. For instance, having read both Hammer's and Curme's German grammar, I am quite used to people talking about the *German subjunctive*. OP's teacher and textbook may be quite happily doing the same. If *subjunctive* is used by scholars, teachers, and textbooks, how can it be "incorrect"?

Comment: Why are we arguing about this? Use comments to improve the question, not to insist on your personal terminological preferences. It's okay to use English terms when talking about German. And I find it quite rude to tell people they are using the wrong term when you don't have a leg to stand on.

Comment: Your logic about skipping a form, since you may use another one, looks flawed to me, since you might need to learn the other form, because you might read or hear it, despite the fact, that you don't need it for writing or speaking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From a pure viewpoint of notion, they are exactly the same.

From a viewpoint of register, Konjunktiv occupies the higher position.

From a viewpoint of day-to-day use, most native speakers tend to use the "Ersatzform" for Konjunktiv II using "würde".

From a viewpoint of grammatical correctness, using the "Ersatzform" is, however, often considered colloquial (but very, very common)

And to answer your question whether you should still learn Konjunktiv II, I can only point out the fact that language is not only *sending*, but rather also *receiving* (i.e. you need to **understand** what people say or write), and they might not always follow your preference of the "Ersatzform". Especially in Konjunktiv sentences it is tricky to follow whether something happened at all, is supposed to happen, may happen, reported to have happened, or allegedly happened,... when you don't know the exact form. So, I'm afraid you will need to learn all of the conjugations.

Comment: Short and to the point. (+1)

Answer (score 6):

*Ich käme* is first person singular Konjunktiv II while *ich würde kommen* is first person singular Konjunktiv II Futur I.

**They mean exactly the same thing in German.**

So you could indeed never use the Konjunktiv II form of anything but *werden* —würden— yourself. The problem with that is that native speakers use those Konjunktiv II forms of other verbs so you at least have to be able to identify and decode them. For example, you have to know that *ich käme* is a form of *kommen* rather than a form of *kämmen*.

You could ask yourself **why** on earth native speakers use those forms. Because they are shortcuts. They are more snappy.

**In practice, you have to know the Konjunktiv II forms of all the auxiliaries, the modals, and some very common verbs as e.g. *geben*, *sehen*, *fallen*, or *kommen* and their prefixed friends.**

As that's what native speakers use all the time. You will hardly ever encounter a Konjunktiv II form of *backen* for example. Even native speakers would have to look that one up. (I looked it up. It's *ich büke*.)

Comment: I also find it fun to look up the forms of “kennen”, which looks so harmless!

Comment: Bevorzugte man den Konjunktiv II gegenüber dem Konjunktiv II Futur I und spräche in der Art, sähen einen die Menschen komisch an und verstünden es nicht auf Anhieb.

Comment: Reimte man dann noch zur Gänze, Literaten täten Tänze. Doch wäre man ein Bösewicht, denn junge Leut' verstünd' es nicht.